# RichEditBox (UWP) ignores font and foreground when setting Rtf text

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, uwp, windows-10

I'm working with a `RichEditBox` and I'm having some problems saving and restoring the Rtf text.

Here's a sample Rtf text I've exported, as you can see there are the different foreground colors and font families saved correctly *(I've manually indented it to make it easier to read)*:

```
{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1040
    {\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}
    {\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Brush Script MT;}
    {\f2\fnil\fcharset0 Impact;}
    {\f3\fnil Segoe UI;}}
{\colortbl ;\red9\green105\blue192;\red0\green0\blue0;\red76\green152\blue25;\red208\green52\blue56;}
{\*\generator Riched20 10.0.14393}\viewkind4\uc1 
\pard\ltrpar\tx720\cf1\b\i\f0\fs23 Test\cf2\b0\i0\par
\pard\ltrpar\li320\qc\tx720\cf3\strike\f1\fs40 Some color\cf2\strike0\f0\fs23\par
\pard\ltrpar\tx720\cf4\f2 Hello!\cf2\f0\par
\f3\par
\f0\lang1033\par
\f3\par
\par
\pard\ltrpar\tx720\fs23\par
}
```

**Problem**: I call

```
EditBox.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, myRtfString);
```

And the text is loaded in the control, but the **font families and the foreground colors are completely ignored**.
I've already tried calling:

```
EditBox.Document.ApplyDisplayUpdates();
```

It doesn't solve the issue. I mean, why is it that all the other paragraph/character options are restored correctly, but *just the font families and foreground colors are ignored*? Am I missing something here?
Thanks!

**Edit**: this is the custom `Style` I'm using for the `RichEditBox`:

```
<Style TargetType="RichEditBox" x:Key="CustomRtfEditBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinWidth}" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemeMinHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="SelectionHighlightColor" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlSelectionHighlightColor}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlThemePadding}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RichEditBox">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="UnFocused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Border x:Name="BorderElement"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Background="{ThemeResource TextControlBackgroundFocused}"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Grid.RowSpan="1" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                    x:DeferLoadStrategy="Lazy"
                                    Visibility="Collapsed"
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    Margin="0,0,0,8"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                    FontWeight="Normal" />
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement"
                                  RequestedTheme="Light"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                                IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                                IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                IsTabStop="False"
                                ZoomMode="Disabled"
                                AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                    <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    IsTabStop="False"
                                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}"
                                    IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue currently cannot be reproduced in newest windows 10 build 14393 by code as follows:

XAML Code

```
... mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="Page_Loaded">
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
   <RichEditBox x:Name="EditBox"  Height="400" Margin="40"   >
   </RichEditBox> 
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind:

```
private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string myRtfString = @"{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1040
 {\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}
 {\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Brush Script MT;}
 {\f2\fnil\fcharset0 Impact;}
 {\f3\fnil Segoe UI;}}
 {\colortbl ;\red9\green105\blue192;\red0\green0\blue0;\red76\green152\blue25;\red208\green52\blue56;}
 {\*\generator Riched20 10.0.14393}\viewkind4\uc1 
 \pard\ltrpar\tx720\cf1\b\i\f0\fs23 Test\cf2\b0\i0\par
 \pard\ltrpar\li320\qc\tx720\cf3\strike\f1\fs40 Some color\cf2\strike0\f0\fs23\par
 \pard\ltrpar\tx720\cf4\f2 Hello!\cf2\f0\par
 \f3\par
 \f0\lang1033\par   
 \f3\par
 \par
 \pard\ltrpar\tx720\fs23\par
 }";
    EditBox.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, myRtfString);
}
```

If you still want a workaround in your environment, please try to find the following code which is under “Focused ViewState” in the style of `RichEditTextBox`  and comment it out. For more details about this please reference [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/1c714fab-7980-46e2-8697-93b5f4c7bd83/xaml-richeditbox-removing-color-formatting?forum=wpdevelop).

```
 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
     <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeBlackHighBrush}"/>
 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="RequestedTheme" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentElement">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Light"/>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

And the result on my side:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I had already removed those visual states (I edited my answer with the complete Style I'm using), I just moved the SetText call into the Loaded event handler as you suggested (I was calling it in the page constructor) and it solved the issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

UWP RichEditBox applies font and color defaults from parent Xaml controls in own OnLoaded event. You can see it by looking onto a call stack in synchronous RichEditBox::TextChanging event handler. Reapplying RTF once again in RichEditBox::OnLoaded event fixes the problem.

In answer above "This issue currently cannot be reproduced in newest windows 10 build 14393 by code as follows..." RTF was set in Page_Loaded, after RichEditBox::OnLoaded that propagates Xaml defaults into RTF.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you have a comment on a previous answer, you should leave it there instead of writing a new answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35064337)