# cannot open my RTF file with my custom fonts

Tags: c#, uwp, rtf, richeditbox

I made my own custom .ttf fonts for my UWP program and put them in Assets folder (vs 2017/2019).  They are working well when the Document is processed in RichEditBox. However, when I Save the RTF file and then Open it, my custom fonts are ignored. If I install my custom fonts beforehand into Windows\Fonts folder , then Open file load the document with my custom fonts. Looks like without installing my custom fonts the program does not link them to the document.

Again - I wrote a program with RichEditBox and my custom fonts in that program. When processed - fonts changed, styles changed, etc - everything goes as designed. When I save RTF file with that program, and open that RTF with that (the same) program - color table is OK but my fonts are not shown though the fonts were compiled with that program (BuildAction - Content; CopyToOutputDirectory - Copy always). To simplify - I made button with the information the file contains. Though fonts are compiled (located in Assets folder), the program does not link them to the document.

Actually with that button I tried to reproduce what is described here: [RichEditBox (UWP) ignores font and foreground when setting Rtf text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40962299/richeditbox-uwp-ignores-font-and-foreground-when-setting-rtf-text) However in my case, the RichEditBox shows only fonts installed in Windows\Fonts directory. How to overcome that and either use links to local fonts compiled with my program or make installer install the fonts to Windows\Fonts directory?
 How could I use my custom fonts (link them to the document) without installing them or what I need to do my UWP program installs my custom fonts to user's device while installing itself?

This is code for button I used to display text:

```
private void Page_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string myRtfString = @"{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\nouicompat\deflang1033{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil MyFont;}{\f1\fnil MyFont1;}{\f2\fnil MyFont2;}} {\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;\red255\green100\blue0;} {\*\generator Riched20 10.0.18362}\viewkind4\uc1 \pard\sl480\slmult1\qj\cf1\highlight2\f0\fs36 tt\highlight3\f1 g\f0 acgt\f2 c\highlight2\f0 tt\highlight0\par}";
    editor.Document.SetText(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, myRtfString);
}
```

This is XAML for RichEditBox:

```
<RichEditBox 
    x:Name="editor"
    Height="200"
    FontFamily="Assets/Fonts/MyFont.ttf#MyFont"
    FontSize="24" RelativePanel.Below="openFileButton"
    RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
    RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True" />
```

Comment: An RTF file does not contain any fonts, it onlt refers to fonts (or font name). If you open your RTF file in another program, where should that other program get the font files your RTF referred to? Many programs just rely on the fonts installed in the operating system, other programs might allow you to specify a custom folder/list with fonts. It all depends on the programs you are using. ymmv...

Comment: What did you do to the code formatting in your question? The code there was already nicely formatted, now the code in your question is basically an unreadable huge single line there. Please pay attention to maintaining good formatting the next time you edit your question ;-)  (FYI: I fixed it)

Comment: And the question is how to manage the program to know that it should open the file with the fonts it put in the file? Or how to manage the program install my custom fonts to the system Fonts directory while program install itself?

Comment: Well, the question as such is fine and would be perfect if you were to hightlight in your question that you open the RTF file with your very same program again, not with another program (see how your current explanation led me to misunderstand your problem in my 1st comment).

Comment: You can open the edit form for your question anytime and see how the current formatting has been achieved. (Basically, keep the code formatted nicely like in your code editor, and surround it with three back-ticks `\`\`\`` above and below a code snippet  ;-) )

Comment: I was talking only about my program, did not mention any other program....

Comment: thank you for your help with question formatting

Comment: About if RTF file contains fonts. First, I did not write that. Second, RTF file could contain embedded fonts: " Font Embedding
An embedded font can be specified by a file name, or the actual font data may be located inside the group. If a file name is specified, it is contained in the \fontfile group. The \cpg control word can be used to specify the character set for the file name. "
Rich Text Format (RTF) Version 1.5 Specification 
http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm#Heading13

Answer (score 1):

Gosha, this way you can apply at least one of the fonts to that .rtf file - see below. For others, I think, you need to use either map information from that .rtf or make an additional map of your own. That will be some "trabajo", but what can you do?

```
         private void applyMyFonts()
    {
            string TextOut;
            MyRichEditBox.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out TextOut);
            MyRichEditBox.Document.Selection.SetRange(0, TextOut.Length);
    MyRichEditBox.Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Name = "Assets/Fonts/MyFont.ttf#MyFont";   
    }

private async void OpenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker open =
           new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
        open.SuggestedStartLocation =
            Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
        open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".rtf");

        Windows.Storage.StorageFile file = await open.PickSingleFileAsync();

        if (file != null)
        {
            try
            {
                Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream randAccStream =
            await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

                // Load the file into the Document property of the RichEditBox.
                MyRichEditBox.Document.LoadFromStream(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, randAccStream);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ContentDialog errorDialog = new ContentDialog()
                {
                    Title = "File open error",
                    Content = "Sorry, I couldn't open the file.",
                    PrimaryButtonText = "Ok"
                };

                await errorDialog.ShowAsync();
            }
        }

        applyMyfonts();
}
```

Comment: Well, I'd say that any other program than yours WOULDN'T, and SHOULDN'T know how to load the fonts from the RTF file. I mean.. If a program is specially made to load RTF, then yes, the font should load. (Because of the references of it in the text. They can be found by loading the RTF File in Notepad.) - But if the program is, say, Notepad or MS-Word, then the RTF will **probably** _not_ load the RTF File, because it's not reading it as RTF, It's reading it as text. If I saved an RTF File, I would load it into my program easily with `richTextBox1.LoadFile("directory");` - It loads the RTF.

Comment: Then again, this question isn't about `RichTextBox` 